# Add spaces to list element HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to add a number of spaces within list string like:

```
<li>Going (25 -going.length spaces added)        to New York</li>
<li>Departing (25 - departing.length spaces added)    to Boston</li>
```

These lines of HTML are prepared in JavaScript and then displayed with jQuery.

But when they are ultimately rendered, the white space is eliminated.  Inspecting the list elements shows that the white space is indeed in the HTML code, but not being displayed.

Any ideas?

**PS**: I just noticed when I had a bunch of spaces in the list items above in this post, the spaces are eliminated from this   post!

Comment: Whitespace is ignored in HTML.

Comment: use `&nbsp;` if you want to force spacing.  since you are preparing the html with javascript, it should be novel to write a `for loop` looping over `25 - going.length` (or however many spaces you want) and then just print `&nbsp;` once in each loop iteration

Comment: Yes, thank you!  That's exactly what I did... and it worked, though it created another problem... which was fixed using a monospaced font!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have -at least- two ways to do what you want:

**1st way:** *which I don't like*

Using `&nbsp;` several times like this

`<li>Going&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to New York</li>`

**2nd way:** *better than 1st way*

surround your `li` item with `<pre></pre>` like this:

```
<li><pre>Going        to New York</pre></li>
<li><pre>Departing        to Boston</pre></li>
```

[HERE IS THE 2nd way EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/c749L/)

Of course you have many other ways with css as other friends suggested, in my answer you will find the HTML solution.

**3rd Way:** *using css:*

HTML:

```
<li class="cssLI"><span class="type">Going to</span><span class="city">New York</span></li>
<li class="cssLI"><span class="type">Departing to</span><span class="city">Boston</span></li>
```

CSS:

```
.cssLI{
    width: 100%;
}
.city{
    float: right;
}
```

**[HERE IS THE 3rd way EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/salota8550/c749L/1/)**

Comment: I've tried the 1st method (with so-so results).  I needed to switch to a monospaced font to keep the spacing consistent.  Though, I'm attracted to the 3rd way, which is really what I wanted in the first place -- to right align the City within the list element.  I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @user3465091 which method you used? `&nbsp;` or the `<pre></pre>` ?

Comment: I used the &nbsp method (actually the &#160 after googling around for ideas)... but like I said, I think the float write method might work better than inserting spaces in a monospaced font.

Comment: @user3465091 it might be because the monospaced font, I can't tell until I see it. but you may use the `<pre></pre>` method **by hitting the `tab` button 2 or 3 times in the place you want the space**.  Or even *better* using the CSS to style it.  *If you have a url that I can visit, I might be able to provide more help.*

Comment: Your method of float:right worked perfectly!!  Thanks!  I wanted the city names to line up throughout the list (which is sorted by city).  I couldn't figure out how to right align just the city name, so the work around was to pick an arbitrary number... 25... and use a for loop to insert spaces after the precending text to total 25 characters.  The problem was that in sans-serif, the 25 characters led to different spacing of the city names.  I'm new to html/css and didn't realize I could use span to modify styling <em>within</em> the list element.  I didn't use the first span "type"...

Comment: @user3465091 Glad I could help :)) all of us are students and new pies.. we learn from each other... keep it up and you will be better and better... and believe me, you will soon start helping others :)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple whitespaces are ignored in HTML and only single whitespace is printed on screen. You can use `&nbsp;` instead.

So this way you can use this code to show 1 whitespace. Your code would be:

```
<li>Going (25 -going.length spaces added)
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to New York</li>
```

This would be rendered as you want it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Its not good to add nbsp; or  to add space instead you may add markup like

```
<ul class="list">
     <li>
            <span>Going </span>
            <span>(25 -going.length spaces added)</span>        
            <span>to New York </span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

and in css you may write as

ul.list li span {display-inline:block; min-width:70px} /*as per your need you may assign class to li */

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Afzaal is right.
It would look like this:

```
<li>Going (25 -going.length spaces added)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to New York</li>
```

Though you can also set it like this (and it's a better practice):

```
 <li>Going (25 -going.length spaces added)<span style="margin-left:40px;">to New York</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `&nbsp;` but it's not a good way. Maybe you can use a table. Or, better, align some `span` or some `div`, and display them with CSS.